# What version of Cocosbuilder and Cocos2d-iphone should I choose?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocosbuilder

Now it's Aug. 25th 2013. When I'm asking this question, the latest stable version of Cocos2d-iphone is 2.1, and the latest stable version of CocosBuilder is 2.1.
I was using Cocos2d-2.0 with CocosBuilder 2.1, testing a tutorial project called cocosdragon code.zynga.c om/2012/10/creating-a-game-with-cocosbuilder/.
However I found that the CCLayerGradient that created is not compatible with cocos2d 2.0, I googled and found others had similar issue. github.c om/cocos2d/CocosBuilder/issues/129

Then I upgrade my cocos2d-iphone to 2.1 version. But this time there're much more problems, because CocosBuilder 2.1 is not 100% compatible with cocos2d 2.1 either. https://github.com/cocos2d/CCBReader/issues/3

And I saw someone says that cocosbuilder v2.1-rc3 can work with cocos-iphone 2.1 beta2, someone recommends to use cocos2d-iphone-2.1-beta4. https://github.com/cocos2d/CocosBuilder/issues/129  I haven't tried out these two suggestions yet.

Because I'm a newbie, and not familiar with Github, nor do I have many knowledge of coding or compiling. So I would like to have suggestions from whoever have related experience. What version of cocos2d-iphone and cocosbuilder should I use?

I'm not willing to use rc(I don't even know what does rc mean) or beta version of cocos2d-ihpone, since there're stable version of cocos2d 2.0 and 2.1.
I'm not willing to use cocosbuilder 3 either because it says there maybe some bugs which would beyond my ability to deal with. (I tried cocosbuilder 3 but can't even find where to get the right CCBReader files)

Thanks for reading this long story. I've taken several days to deal with this problem, but failed. I even messed up my old project in the process of updating cocos2d from 2.0 rc1 to 2.1 without keep a napshot. I just don't know where to ask, any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Throw the idea of alpha/beta/rc/stable over board - stable versions have bugs while beta builds can be very stable too. So you really only need to find a combination of cocos2d + cb that work well together. Honestly I'm surprised that CB doesn't fully support cocos2d 2.1 yet. Considering that you have little experience with coding & compiling, perhaps you should first start with more userfriendly tools: Game Maker, Stencyl, Game Salad, perhaps even Corona (scripting with Lua)?

Comment: OMG, are you the real Steffen the author of LearnCocos2D? Thanks a lot for your advice! I'll try to use CB 2.1 with cocos2d2.1 rc version later after my breakfast. I only have one "real" project experience after learning some examples of cocos2d. But I found it's too complex to write a full game only with Cocos2d and texture packer(especially animation\UI design\my own menu and level system). I guess this is not the right way to develop games as an tobe-indie-developer. I chose cocos2d builder to try simply because it's famous. I'll try your advice such as Gamer Maker, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the advises Steffen. I've spent some time continue reading your books, and did some research on different tools. Then I found Stencyl is good, so I tried it with the crashing source examples. However in the end, I found that maybe it's not suitable to me. Because I want to become more professional in making games, at least a free lancer that can live on making games, but the Stencyl so far seems too "unhardcore" to me. I don't have the control of many things compared with Cocos2D. And it's hard to upgrade my games to online version for example.

Comment: Before asking this question, I was working on a Whack A Mole game. It was too complex to edit the levels, animations, and skills/talent scene using only Cocos2D. Now after trying different tools, I decide to try CocosBuilder again, seems it can cut lots of the works compared only using Cocos2d. I'd like to have your opinions whether my thoughts on Stencyl and Cocos2d+cocosbuilder have problems. And if my goal is to make games like Badlands, Kingdomrush, and games with servers, I'm on the right track studying cocos2d(with Box2D)+cocosbuilder, instead of Stencyl. Thanks a lot!